# puppeteer - Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, dom, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape https://www.amazon.com/s?k=macbook+pro&ref=nb_sb_noss

The below code works when I execute it chrome dev tools (console) but it throws an error: `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')` in puppeteer. I'm able to scrape the page with className identifiers for other elements, but not this one.

```
let raters = document.getElementsByClassName('s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col s-widget-spacing-small sg-col-12-of-16')[0].querySelectorAll(".a-size-base.puis-light-weight-text.s-link-centralized-style", "span")[0].innerText
```

How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the element is not being populated dynamically/asynchronously?

Comment: Please share the Puppeteer code.